# How can I setup kubeapi server to allow kubectl from outside the cluster

Tags: authentication, kubernetes

I have a single master, multinode kubernetes going. It works great. However I want to allow kubectl commands to be run from outside the master server. How do I run kubectl get node from my laptop for example?

If I install kubectl on my laptop I get the following error:
error: client-key-data or client-key must be specified for kubernetes-admin to use the clientCert authentication method

How do I go about this. I have read through the kubernetes authorisation documentation but I must say it's a bit greek to me. I am running version 1.10.2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend  [@sfgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344669/sfgroups) answer:

Configurations of all [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) clusters you are managing
are stored in $HOME/.kube/config file. If you have that file on the master node,
the easy way is to copy it to $HOME/.kube/config file on a local machine.
You can choose other places, and then specify the location by environment value `KUBECONFIG`:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/config
```

or use `--kubeconfig` command line parameter instead.

Cloud providers often give you a possibility to download config to local machine from the
web interface or by the cloud management command.

For [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/):

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]`

For [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/):

```
az login -u yourazureaccount -p yourpassword
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=<cluster-resource-group> --name=<cluster-name>
```

If the cluster was created using [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) utility, you could get the config file by:

```
kops export kubeconfig ${CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Comment: Hi, I did do that, but copied it again as suggested, but it turns out I need to run --username as well. I used kubeadm to setup: kubectl get nodes --username kubernetes-admin --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config

Answer (score 0):

From your master copy **/root/.kube** directory to your laptop **C:\Users\.kube** location.

kubectl will pickup the certificate from config file automatically.